# What causes CORS errors to show up after lengthy periods between deployment

Tags: reactjs, ruby, typescript, nginx

I have been experiencing a rather strange development in the React/Ruby application. This is my second application using the same tech stack, and on both occasions, this happened.
After the initial deployment to my NGINX server, everything worked fine. I do continuous deployment as I develop, then I get to a point where I stretch the development period, which means I have a lot more to deploy, and usually this is where these CORS errors begin to show up. I usually have to retrace my steps back to the last working push I made to my GitHub repository and then redeploy that, then resume working from there. If I do the deployment in short bursts, I don't get this problem, but if I back it up for a long time before deploying, this error happens.